# Does being a technomancer affect AR needs?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, technomancer

I know technomancers have a living VR Persona and can thread Complex Forms to simulate most programs in the Matrix, but what about simple AR? Do they need a Complex Form or hardware for AR feed, or do they get it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A technomancer is considered in AR by default so you perceive, without any special gear, with all your senses, the icons and other AROs of the Matrix in permanence. Your persona not only live in VR but also in AR. Unless you turn your persona off you can perceive the Matrix like you had cybereyes, cyberears and AR gloves. They can also be connected to the Matrix when they are sleeping as detailed in Unwired. This way a Technomancer can receive messages, calls, feedback from his sprites etc.

Answer (score 0):

Shadowrun 4th Edition Anniversary, p.221 (emphasis mine)

> In accordance with their affinity for the technological world,
>   technomancers have an instinctive awareness of the fluctuations of
>   data around them. This subliminal sense not only functions in the VR
>   of the Matrix, but **in the real world as well**, where technomancers can
>   “feel” the wireless data traffic flowing through the airwaves around
>   them.

Although please note that in order to use "smart" weapons, the technomancer needs to acquire the tactical software that translates raw data into visual aiming aids, so he needs to learn (or thread) the Smartlink Complex Form. It is learned like any other Complex Form with a rating of 1 (Unwired p.136)